# Loading jQuery externally for a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a bookmarklet that will capture some parameters from a URL and send that to a script (the url in the post is just a dummy atm).

The problem is, I try to include jQuery to the page so I can use a $.post later. When trying to run the bookmarklet I get the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I can see the jQuery is succesfully appended by looking at the Elements tab in the browser. Any tips on how to solve this?

You can see the bookmarklet below:

```
javascript: 

function appendScript() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
    head.appendChild(script);

}

appendScript();

function parseUri (str) {
    var o   = parseUri.options,
        m   = o.parser[o.strictMode ? "strict" : "loose"].exec(str),
        uri = {},
        i   = 14;

    while (i--) uri[o.key[i]] = m[i] || "";

    uri[o.q.name] = {};
    uri[o.key[12]].replace(o.q.parser, function ($0, $1, $2) {
        if ($1) uri[o.q.name][$1] = $2;
    });

    return uri;
};

parseUri.options = {
    strictMode: false,
    key: ["source","protocol","authority","userInfo","user","password","host","port","relative","path","directory","file","query","anchor"],
    q:   {
        name:   "queryKey",
        parser: /(?:^|&)([^&=]*)=?([^&]*)/g
    },
    parser: {
        strict: /^(?:([^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/((?:(([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?)?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?((((?:[^?#\/]*\/)*)([^?#]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/,
        loose:  /^(?:(?![^:@]+:[^:@\/]*@)([^:\/?#.]+):)?(?:\/\/)?((?:(([^:@]*)(?::([^:@]*))?)?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?)(((\/(?:[^?#](?![^?#\/]*\.[^?#\/.]+(?:[?#]|$)))*\/?)?([^?#\/]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/
    }
};

couponCode = parseUri(window.location.search).queryKey['couponCode'];
customerId = parseUri(window.location.search).queryKey['customerId'];

function showModal() {
    if (couponCode != null) {
        alert("Here is your coupon. Make sure to use it at checkout!" + couponCode);
    }
}

showModal();

function parakeetCommunicator() {

    if (couponCode != null) {
        console.log("Sending data to Parakeet...");

        $.post( "http://test.com/datascript.go", { customerId: customerId, couponCode: couponCode }) 
            .done(function( data ) {
               console.log("Succesfully posted the coupon was viewed to Parakeet server.");
            });
        }
}

parakeetCommunicator();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script is loaded asychronously, you could fix it using onload event of script e.g:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.onload = parakeetCommunicator;
script.src = ...;
```

And remove other call to this method.

If you only need jQuery for relative ajax wrapper, you should be interrested in building your own jquery version to support only these methods, see: http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/